# How to find mentions of a string in all directory files?

Tags: search, perl

I will describe my task:
I have a lot of directories with a lot of perl-files. I need to find all files that mention the string "license.key". What ways can this be implemented?

Comment: Hello. After YOU have written the script you can post it here and someone may be able to point out any errors. If you expect someone to write it for you, you have come to the wrong place.

Comment: Hi. Write a script? Is there really no such utility?